# create tabbarcontroller on the fly and assign it to the view other than rootview of window

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, rootviewcontroller

I want to use a third-party library which implements a nice tabbar controller. But it does all the work programmatically, basically all it does is create two uiviewcontrollers and add them to a tabbarcontroller, and then instantiate an uinavigationcontroller with the tabbarcontroller. In the last step, it assigns the uinavigationcontroller to the rootviewcontroller of the window like the following:

```
self.window?.rootViewController = getNavigationController()
```

But I want to use this navigationcontroller in a place other than the rootviewcontroller of the window, say like I want to push from another view and goes to this navigationcontroller. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

You can present it modally over your current navigation controller from your current viewcontroller

```
let vc = myNavigationControllerWithTabBarControllerInside() //change this to your navigation controller
self.navigationController.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please verify, for your self.navigationController to not be nil. otherwise, use

```
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: For this to work, your current viewController should be a child of UINavigationController, i.e to be pushed inside navigation Controller .

Please verify, for your self.navigationController to not be nil.

otherwise, use

self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)